Bluetooth permission error in service class
I m building an Android application that should to use device connected by Bluetooth to read some values.
So this is my service class:
package it.mc.service;

import static android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import it.eresult.silvermountain.model.SensorModel;
import it.eresult.silvermountain.utils.PreferenceHandler;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p>
 * <p>
 * TODO: Customize class - update intent actions, extra parameters and static
 * helper methods.
 */
public class SensorService extends IntentService {

    // TODO: Rename actions, choose action names that describe tasks that this
    // IntentService can perform, e.g. ACTION_FETCH_NEW_ITEMS
    public static final String tag = "Ssensors";
    
    // TODO: Rename parameters
    private static final String EXTRA_PARAM1 = "it.eresult.silvermountain.service.extra.PARAM1";
    private static final String EXTRA_PARAM2 = "it.eresult.silvermountain.service.extra.PARAM2";

    public long dosimeterScanningTime;
    private Context mContext;
    private String macAddress;
    private int mStatus;
    //private BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    List<SensorModel> listaSensori = new ArrayList<SensorModel>();

    public SensorService() {
        super("SensorService");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(tag, "ON HANDLE INTENT");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            Log.d(tag, "No macAddress configuration");
        }
        else {
            String firstMacAddress = (String) extras.get("firstDevice");
            String secondMacAddress = (String) extras.get("secondDevice");

            //questa parte di codice va rivista
            if (intent != null) {
                String action = intent.getStringExtra(PreferenceHandler.ACTION);

                Log.d(tag, action != null ? action : "no action");
                if (action != null && action.equals(PreferenceHandler.ACTION_CHANGE_SCANNING_ROTATION_TIME)) {
                    Log.d(tag, "modifico il servizio");
                    //todo questa parte va rivista
                    int rTime = 10;
                    int sTime = 10;
                    dosimeterScanningTime = sTime;
                    Log.d(tag, "val new " + dosimeterScanningTime);
                    //provo a vedere se la modifica ha risolto qualcosa
                    return;
                } else if (action != null && action.equals(PreferenceHandler.ACTION_STOP)) {
                    Log.d(tag, "fermo il servizio");
                    dosimeterScanningTime = 0;

                    //provo a vedere se la modifica ha risolto qualcosa
                    return;
                }
            }
            mContext = this;
            dosimeterScanningTime = 100;
            SensorModel s = new SensorModel();
            s.setMacAddress(firstMacAddress);
            listaSensori.add(s);
            s = new SensorModel();
            s.setMacAddress(secondMacAddress);
            listaSensori.add(s);
            for(int i=0;i< listaSensori.size();i++) {
                connectDevice(i, listaSensori.get(i).getMacAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectDevice(int tagDevice, String mac) {
        listaSensori.get(tagDevice).setConnectionState(0);//connecting
        macAddress = mac;
        Log.d(tag, "Try to connect device: "+mac);
        mStatus = BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
        if( listaSensori.get(tagDevice).getmConnGatt()==null){
            Log.w(tag, "new connect :: "+ listaSensori.get(tagDevice).getMacAddress());
            BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(mac);
            if (device == null) {
                Log.w(tag, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
                return;
            }
            try {
                BluetoothGatt mConnGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback, TRANSPORT_LE);
                boolean connect = mConnGatt.connect();
                boolean discoverService = mConnGatt.discoverServices();
                Log.w(tag, connect+" " + discoverService);
                listaSensori.get(tagDevice).setmConnGatt(mConnGatt);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(tag,"ConnectGatt exception caught " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            Log.d(tag, gatt.getDevice().getAddress()+ " onConnectionStateChange, status " +status+" newState: " + newState);
            if(newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED){
                //
                Log.d(tag, "connessione con device avvenuta correttamente " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                gatt.discoverServices();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            Log.d(tag, gatt.getDevice().getAddress()+" onServicesDiscovered");
            for(BluetoothGattService service: gatt.getServices()){
                String serviceUUID = service.getUuid().toString();
                //Log.e("OnServicesDiscovered", "Service uuid: "+serviceUUID );
                if(serviceUUID.contains("0000ffff")){
                    Log.d(tag, "OnServicesDiscovered LETTURA DA Service uuid: "+serviceUUID );
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> mListCars = service.getCharacteristics();
                    //leggo le caratteristiche del servizio che cerco
                    for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic bc : mListCars){
                        //recupero solo le caratteristiche 1131, 1132

                        if(bc.getUuid().toString().contains("0000fff4")){
                            Log.d(tag,"OnServicesDiscovered "+ bc.getUuid().toString() );
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(service.getUuid()).getCharacteristic(bc.getUuid());
                            if(characteristic==null)
                                Log.d(tag,"OnServicesDiscovered characteristic NULL");
                            else
                                gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,int status) {
            Log.d(tag, gatt.getDevice().getAddress()+" onCharacteristicRead");
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            Log.d(tag, "Leggo quaternioni "+ new String(data) + " " +characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                          BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            Log.d(tag,gatt.getDevice().getAddress()+ " >>onCharacteristicWrite");

        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            Log.d(tag,">>onCharacteristicChanged");
        }
    };
}

So Android Studio show my error in

This is the permissions in AndroidManifest file:
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

This is the Activity that called Service
public class BackgroundActivityBLE extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GPS = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean bluetoothAvailable = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);

        boolean bluetoothLEAvailable = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String [] { android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT },1
            );
        }
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_background_ble);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        Intent sensorService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SensorService.class);
        sensorService.putExtra("firstDevice", "10:7C:61:27:5C:56");
        sensorService.putExtra("secondDevice", "10:7C:61:27:5C:64");
        startService(sensorService);
    }

    private void checkPermissions(){

    }

}

How can I fix error on check permissions in Service class?

click the button in that info dialog in your screen shot that says "Add permission check" and it will surround it with an if check
